# How to replace string with variable in Helm template?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have this template:

```yaml
{{- $service_port := 1010 }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ $.Values.name }}
data:
    {{- range $key, $val := .Values.configmap }}
      {{- if contains "<ServicePort>" $val }}
    {{ $key }}: '{{ $val | replace "<ServicePort>" {{ $service_port }} }}'
```

I need to replace it with `service_port` defined at the beginning of a file. How can I achieve this? The code above does not seem to work.

Comment: At the end of the line you should just be able to use the variable `$service_port`; you don't need the extra set of `{{ curly braces }}`.

Comment: Did you get this running? What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It replaces all `serviceName` tokens with the real service name.

```yaml
    appSettings: |    
        {{ $name := include "myService.fullname" . }}
        <appSettings>
          {{- $root := . }}
          {{- range $key, $value := .Values.appSettings }}          
          <add key={{ $key | quote }} value={{ $value | quote | replace "#{serviceName}#" $name }} />
          {{- end }}
        </appSettings>
```

Important part was that the replace function was used as the last one. Before it finally worked, I'd tried using replace before the quote function.